# SVG pixelate when using with canvas in full window height and width for all devices

Tags: javascript, svg, canvas, fullscreen

I'm using Jspain library in this project.
https://faisalsamroz.com/colorway15/

I drawed SVG image on canvas but it's pixelating even it shows white dots when you fill up black color.
Screenshot attached.
Please help if someone else faced the same problem.

[image: 1]

Comment: Can you link us to the original SVG image? (your current link is to a PNG file, but I'm sure you know that)

Comment: @BarryCarter I used this SVG image.
https://faisalsamroz.com/colorway15/images/colorway-web-logo-outline.svg

Comment: Could you please explain more about what you mean when you write "when you fill up black color"?

Comment: @LukeWoodward Yes, when you fill up the color by using "fill with color" tools, it shows white spots around the edges. You can see that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an SVG is rendered to a bitmap - such as a canvas - antialiasing is used to make the edges of the shapes appear smoother.

[image]

If you then try to [flood fill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) those bitmap shapes with a colour, those grey edge pixels are going to appear like white lines or spots around the edge of the fill.

There are a few things you can do.  For example:

1. You can disable anti-aliasing in your SVG images. Use `shape-rendering="crispEdges"` as a property or CSS style.  See: https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/single-page.html#painting-ShapeRenderingProperty, or
2. Render the SVG. Then run a threshhold or contrast filter over that image to remove the grey pixels.